# Can we have a Master UserControl act as an interface to inherit from that?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone 8 app I need to have a few UserControl which all of them have same functions (only the header not the body). I am wondered if i can have some thing like interface so i can inherit from that? (i could do it in ios with UIViewController)

Answer (score 1):

If you're extending the same basic idea you may be best to look at creating a Custom Control and then adding what your body as Content inside it the control. You can then re-skin your custom control as you need in each case (and learn more about how controls work as a side-effect).

It's a bit more work than creating a UserControl, but it sounds appropriate for what you're doing and is the idiomatic way of solving this kind of problem in XAML/.NET (WP, Windows Store, WPF).

There is a good article on the differences between User Control and Custom Controls on [WindowsPhoneGeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/User-Control-vs-Custom-Control-in-Silverlight-for-WP7).

Comment: @ Paul Annetts: Maybe more detail will help to get better answer. i should see each user control like a subview which can contain any control/controls. I will instantiate each user control in mainpage and call some functions later.

Comment: @finutv that's called a ContentControl in XAML. No problem you can do that - and that's even mentioned in the Windows Phone Geek article I linked to.

Comment: I have solved the problem with creating abstract user control as parent and the other user controls inherit from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class MasterUserControl : UserControl
{
[...]
}

public class MyUserControl : MasterUserControl
{
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: @ robertftw: implementing this return the error "missing partial modifier on declaration of type... another partial declaration of this type exists" the problem will be gone if i set the build action to resource which i am not sure it is a right way to correct.Besides it seems i cant have the InitializeComponent(), So i dont know if i need this function or not. (note that i create all controls in user control dynmically in code)